# Can i build an Android app that uses Firebase authentication but a custom database(eg MySQL)

Tags: android, mysql, database, firebase, video-streaming

I want to build an Android app that uses firebase authentication google sign in. But want to use a custom database(eg MySQL) which will store some video files.

I want to keep a track of the videos that my users will be watching.

Can i connect the firebase to my custom database so that it can hold data of the user's behaviors.

Comment: There is no need to connect Firebase to SQL db. Just get UserId and user related data (if needed) from firebase and track which userId (user) watching which video in your code.

Comment: Thanks you, I am new to this, can you link to a few resources or tutorials that can help me do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking if you can use Firebase Authentication, but use your own database, that's fine.  You have the option of picking and choosing which parts of Firebase meet your needs.  You need not commit to any part of Firebase that does not.

If you're asking if Firebase (both Realtime Database and Firestore) can act as a proxy for other databases, that's not possible.